# How can I root my Samsung Infuse 4G (AT&T)?

Tags: rooting, samsung-infuse-4g

I have been looking everywhere online, but I cannot find anything helpful in rooting my Samsung Infuse 4G. I have even tried (once) with SuperOneClick, but it never worked. Didn't affect my phone, but it did lock my pc up for a bit. Does anyone have any helpful advice?

Answer (score 1):

Rooting a phone generally does not affect it visibly much, other than a new "Superuser" app in the app drawer.  Rooting only provides ability to gain elevated privileges, with the Superuser app acting like the gatekeeper for other apps requesting such privileges.

SuperOneClick is the preferred method for rooting the Infuse 4G.  If you're unsure if that succeeded, here's what you can try to check if your phone was indeed rooted:

1. From the Market install the [Terminal Emulator](https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app.
2. Launch the app, and using the on-screen keyboard type in `su` and press Enter.
3. If your phone is rooted, a new dialog named "Superuser Request" should come up. Tap the "Allow" button.
4. You should see a pound sign `#`. Now type in `reboot` and press Enter.

If at this point your phone reboots, you have root.  Otherwise you will receive the following message "`reboot: Operation not permitted`"  This means the rooting did not complete successfully and you may want to re-try it by following any of [many](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-samsung-infuse-4g-on-android-2-2-with-superoneclick/) [guides](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1293751) [found](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-02NrvxDZYA) [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=infuse+4g+root).

P.S. Please be sure to follow the guide designed for your specific device.  Not all Infuses are the same - there are differences between the AT&T version and Rogers', for example.